# How the service will inject an object, which it needs e.g. 5 minutes to be calculated?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, service

My question is partly a theoretical one and I would like to know, what would happen if we want to inject an object, which is in the example below 'user', through a service showed when the object itself (user) needs e.g. 5 minutes to calculate a certain attribute (e.g. total purchasing over lifetime). Does the service wait until the calculation is done or what is exactly going to happen?
Thanks in advance

this following example is from "https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.5.0.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html"

```
@Service
class UserManagementImpl implements UserManagement {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final RoleRepository roleRepository;

    @Autowired
    public UserManagementImpl(UserRepository userRepository, RoleRepository roleRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.roleRepository = roleRepository;
    }

    @Transactional
    public void addRoleToAllUsers(String roleName) {
        Role role = roleRepository.findByName(roleName);

        for (User user : userRepository.findAll()) {
            user.addRole(role);
            userRepository.save(user);
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Unclear: JPA has no notion of injection or of service at all. Please provide a concrete example, and explain what takes 5 minutes.

Comment: I tried to add some codes. I hope that the question is a bit more clear now :-)

Comment: user is not "injected" in the above code. What is injected is userRepository and roleRepository. user is just one of the entities returned by the findAll() method of the repository. Once again, it's not clear what in this code would take 5 minutes. You talk about the "total purchasing over lifetime" of the user, but that doesn't appear anywhere in the code you posted. I can only guess that the total puchasing over lifetime would be a OneToMany association in User, and OneToMany associations are loaded lazily by default. So the above code wouldn't load it at all.

Comment: That said, if it takes 5 minutes to load the elements of that collection, it should probably not be mapped as a collection in the first place.